What do I do with a botched luxury click vinyl flooring job?
I got luxury click vinyl flooring installed in the basement, right over concrete.
I went to one of the 'well name' brands in town...
We noted the basement was uneven we were quoted $1,000 for grinding and leveling as required, which may go up or may go down, depending on how much was required.
They did some leveling and grinding and started to lay floor.
2nd day comes and I notice a few concern areas - feels uneven - floor flexing when I step on it - I flag this for buddy installing and he says not to worry and things will 'settle'... he adjusts some of the plastic underlay, it's better, but still quite concerned...
3rd day he is done. I walk around. Clearly feeling uneven spots where I step, I can feel it's a few mm off the concrete when I step on it. Creaks and can hear sound when you step on certain areas.
By taking a 4-foot level, I can clearly see raised and lower spots on the luxury click vinyl flooring.
Installer was gone by the time I got home to check any of this.
Now what do I do? It's not a good job, I could have done this myself, but I specifically hired one of the better-named flooring companies around to do this install, at a premium, and it's like a crackhead installed it. Of course they demanded 75% payment before starting.
What do I do?

I think the condition of the install is terrible, even if I don't pay another cent - it's clown work. Even with a 25% "discount" - I'm super unhappy with this work.

The proper fix is to rip up all the luxury click vinyl flooring (I don't think this can be done without damaging it), level it properly, and re-lay, likely with new material - which I'm not paying for.

???


The 'salesman' is back tomorrow from vacation and he has been my contact the entire process. I've already sent him an email saying we need to chat and to follow up with me ASAP. He returns tomorrow.
Other notes:
I have a breakdown of the total time spent on the job, and exactly what the installer was doing during this time. In total, he might have spent 2, MAYBE 3 hours leveling the entire basement, clearly missing massive spots.
The install was delayed a week because "they couldn't find my order" - thus the salesman was gone when the install was being done.
I'm now still in limbo because I refuse to move my furniture or do trim work before this guy comes to check out this work.
Right now, the only way to make it right is to rip it up, level the basement, like I was quoted, and install it properly. But since I don't think luxury click vinyl flooring can be reused, nor do I think I WANT it reused, I think they are just going to try and say we will knock 25% off the bill, which I still don't think is acceptable, it's awful work.

Are you looking to DIY this work now?

Those floors click together, not saying it is easy, they unclick also.  They also have a limited amount of non flat they allow.  Laying over vinyl sheet with patches out of it is okay, a dip/ridge of 3/16 is not.

I’m voting to close this question because it's a rant, not a specific question (looking for ideas is vague, and vague does not work here.) Also, save your cuss words for the company you hired, it's freakin' childish to inflict them on the readers here.

This may be a horrible job, or you may be overreacting. It is true that small imperfections in the subfloor may be felt underfoot and a creak can be heard, but it is also true that the floor will settle and these things will go away. However it takes longer than a day.
I have experienced the same in my own home. It took about a week before the floor "relaxed". You need to use the space to help the floor conform to the imperfections.
Perhaps you should agree to a time frame to allow the floor to conform. Something like 2 to 3 weeks. Then if it still is not acceptable, have it redone.  Be sure to outline how and with what materials it will be redone with.

I appreciate the response - I'll take a deep breath and wait a few more days to assess.. I'll take your comments to heart
